# ndiswrapper isn't working?

Tags: ndiswrapper

So, I have a `Belkin Components F7D4101 / F9L1101 802.11abgn Wireless Adapter` and its installation disk with supplied drivers and such. I went about using `ndisrapper`, but to no prevail.. This is my first time using ndiswrapper, so I followed [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0Ist9aEKEg) tutorial. Looking with `ndiswrapper -l`, my driver seems to be installed, but when I get to the point in the tutorial when he types `ndiswrapper -m`, it says,

```
module configuration already contains alias directive

module configuration already contains alias directive

module configuration already contains alias directive
```

I've tried a simple reboot, but that didn't do anything, so can someone help?

Comment: Are there any clues here: dmesg | grep ndis. Did you use the Windows XP inf and sys files?

Comment: @chili555, I actually tried both, neither of which worked.As for any further clues, I neither have, nor do I know how to get any.

Comment: If you tried the XP files and they didn't work, what exactly are you using?? Was there no response to the terminal command dmesg | grep ndis? That funny pipe symbol | is on the right side of my US keyboard on the same key with \.